# Installing JDK 1.6 and maven2 on Vagrant Box

Tags: vagrant, vagrantfile

I am trying to install `jdk 1.6` and `maven2` on my vagrant box.
But most of the times installation of those two packages fails. I am using following command to install the same.

```
sudo apt-get install openjdk-6-jdk
sudo apt-get install maven2
```

Comment: To help identify the problem, can you include a copy of your Vagrantfile and also the output of the install commands?

Comment: Most of the time? What's different when it works?